# How do I add .NET Core class library reference in Service Fabric App

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-service-fabric, microsoft-graph-api

How do I add `.NET Core class library` reference in `Service Fabric App`.
While I'm adding Class Library reference (`.NET Core`) in `WebAPI app`, showing Compatibility issues. Please find below What I did, using Visual Studio 2017.

```
File >> New Project >> Cloud >> Service Fabric Application
Name - FirstServiceFabricApp

Select a Template >> Stateless ASP.NET Core 
Name - FirstStatelessAPI
```

Build and Run the Project. It works.

Although API Project Framework version is `.NET Framework 4.5.2.`

[image]

Added Class Library Project [`builds on .NET Core 1.1`] as reference into Stateless WebAPI Project. Showing compatibility issues-

[image]

Building the solution x64 platform.

My concerns are:

1. How do I take .NET Core Library reference in Stateless WebAPI Project [Service Fabric]
2. Should I go/develop with .NET Framework for Class Library which is compatible with Stateless WebAPI project.
3. I did Azure AD Authentication/Microsoft Graph in Azure APP Service, but never did for Service Fabric App. Whether Azure AD and Microsoft Graph implementation is same in this `Stateless WebAPI App`. Kindly provide some references on this.

Comment: Make your class library target a compatible framework (e.g. netstandard1.X or net452)

Comment: Thanks.Only Net_Framework (4.5.2) is supporting and net standard 1.X is not supported in Stateless API service [compatibility issue].Will start developing in .NET Framework (4.5.2) for Class Library.

Comment: @Mardoxx Consider making your comment an answer so that you get the reputation and this question doesn't show up as unsolved in search.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your class library target a compatible framework e.g. net452 (or netstandard2.0 when it's supported like 2017 Q3)

Answer (score 0):

The below link talks about converting a .net core to azure service fabric application.

It talks about statefulservice. Statelessservice is more or less similar to it.

http://dotnetextensions.blogspot.in/2018/04/convert-dot-net-core-application-to.html?m=1

When it comes to azure ad, i won't have much impact. You can continue to use the same thing